# What's the difference between "schon" and "noch" in questions?

Tags: difference, question

> Wie lange hast du schon Urlaub?
>   Wie lange hast du noch Urlaub?

What's the difference between these two questions? Are they answered differently? Is it like one of them started the holidays but the other one hasn't started yet?

Comment: What did you find out so far? Did you try a translator for "schon" and "noch"?

Comment: Advanced: "Du hast aber schon noch Urlaub?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Your holiday begins ----------------- Now ----------------- Your
>   holiday ends

Wie lange hast du schon Urlaub?

In this question, the time span from `Your holiday begins` until `Now` is asked.

> **(Your holiday begins ----------------- Now)** ----------------- Your
>   holiday ends

Wie lange hast du noch Urlaub?

In this question, the time span from `Now` until `Your holiday ends` is asked.

> Your holiday begins ----------------- **(Now ----------------- Your**
>   **holiday ends)**

Comment: +1 for the thought of a "graphical timeline"

Comment: @tofro haha thanks. I am a visual learner. That is why, I find this kind of answers very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

> Wie lange hast du schon Urlaub?

Here, you ask for the time that has already passed (*schon* = *already*).

---

> Wie lange hast do noch Urlaub?

Here, you ask for the time still left (*noch* = *still*).